# Multiple API requests with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to call multiple external api within for loop but as per the result i am getting  only one iteration from the for loop sending the response back.

Yes, its not the right approach to handle multi api request, please suggest the best approach as it has to be sequential req/res

First Request -  Call to find respective api. Response holds the data to feed into two api which are called within for-loop.

For-loop Second API Request - feeds data to the third API request.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Request = require("request");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/building/', function (req, res) {
 'use strict';

 var myObject = null;

 var callSiteApi = {
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/site/',
  body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
 }
 // First External API Call
 Request(callSiteApi, function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
   console.log('ERROR with user request.');
   return response.sendStatus(500); // Return back that an error occurred
  } else {
   // Get data from response.body

    
   var materialquerystring = "mat="+response.body.material+"&date="+response.body.date;
            var floor = response.body.floor;

   for (var i = 0; i < floor.length; i++) {

    matereialValueURL = "http://localhost:8080/material/q="+materialquerystring;
    // Second External API Call within for loop
    Request.get(materialValueURL, (error, response, body) => {
     if (error) {
      console.log(req.error);
      
     }
     materialObject = JSON.parse(body);
          var valuequerystring = "value="+materialObject.value;
          // do somehting with materialObject
          
     console.log("first request iteration =" + i);

     sitevalueURL = "http://localhost:8080/value/q="+valuequerystring;
     // Third External API Call within for loop
     Request.get(sitevalueURL, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
       logger.debug('[' + pid + '] ' + req.error);
       //return console.dir(error);
      }
      valueObject = JSON.parse(body);           
            console.log("second request iteration =" + i);
            // do somehting with valueObject 7 materialObject
            var a = materialObject.a;
            var b = valueObject.b;
            var c = a+b;
            
      
     });
    });
   }

   res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   });
   res.end('{"value-1":"a","value-2":"b","value-3":"c","material":"materialquerystring","value":"valuequerystring"}');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with how callbacks work. In your first `Request`'s callback, calling `return` will not work like you think it does, and the `response` is the one from the API call, not `res` from your `/building/` route handler. And making multiple requests like that isn't going to work with a simple for loop; you'll need `Promise.all()` for that.

Comment: thanks, any good example I can refer?

Comment: It's going to look something like this: https://pastebin.com/CuEd6q71

Comment: chris, for every for loop two api request are called and do something with the both their response before another iteration. e.g. 2 iteration of for loops will have 2x2=4 external api request. This is where i am getting stuck. With promise I need 2nd & 3rd api http://localhost:8080/material/ & http://localhost:8080/value/ in for loop. I hope i made sense

Comment: No, you just call Promise.all() inside Promise.all(). Or you create an array containing all 4 requests, then call Promise.all() on it.

Comment: I have edited the example code, please have a look at what i am trying to achieve.  Its very kind of you to help me out.

Comment: Do you understand my code? You just need to make minimal changes to it and it should be working fine. On the other hand you might want to think about changing your API so it sends all that information as one big JSON text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to get a number from the user's request, and then issue the same http request that number of times, something like this should do. I brought in a pointfree `map` helper from [crocks](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks) to make things a little easier.

You might need to make a few adjustments here and there, particularly in the final `then` clause

```
const map = require('crocks/pointfree/map');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const range = integer => [...new Array(integer).keys()]
const replicate = (i, x) => range(i).fill(x)

const handleError = error => {
  logger.debug(`['${pid}'] ${error.reponse.error}`)
  return error;
}

const getMaterialURIs = response =>
  replicate(response.body.floor.length, `http://localhost:8080/material/q=${response.body.material}`)

const processMaterialResponse = response => {
  doSomethingWithMaterial(response.body)
  return response;
}

const getSiteValueURI = response =>
  `http://localhost:8080/value/q=${response.body.value}`;

const processSiteValueResponse = response => {
  doSomethingWithSiteValue(response.body)
  return response;
}

app.post('/building/', function (req, res) {
  const uri = 'http://localhost:8080/site/';
  const body = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  const method = 'POST';
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

  // First External API Call
  Request({uri, body, method, headers})
    // 1: fetch to derive the material URI
    .then(getMaterialURIs)
    // 2: fetch from that material URI
    .then(map(Request.get))
    .then(Promise.all)
    // 3: process the material response
    .then(map(processMaterialResponse))
    // 4: derive the siteValueURI 
    .then(map(getSiteValueURI))
    // 5: fetch the siteValueURI
    .then(map(Request.get))
    .then(Promise.all)
    // 6: process the site value response
    .then(map(processSiteValueResponse))
    .catch(handleError)
    .then(response => {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      res.end('{"material":"materialquerystring","value":"valuequerystring"}');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks benny, can you have a look at the code now i have corrected.

Comment: if i understood you correctly, the edited answer should fit your case better

Comment: `$ node sequence.js
D:\sandbox\tax\sequence.js:36
app.post('/building/', function (req, res) {
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` @benny-powers

Comment: Its working, thanks. But again its iterating only once.  The project is I need to find number of floors that's the first api http://localhost:8080/site/. Based on the floors i need to find material and site value for each floor . So I have to put 2nd & 3rd api in loop until no. of floors is exhausted.

Comment: The last response should hold few fields from response body/data of 1st, 2nd, 3rd api

Comment: There's nothing in the url you're fetching from which relates to the floor in question, though.

Comment: its there, var floor = response.body.floor;

Comment: @ benny-powers, I am still struggling to fix this loop. for loop is executing only once. Can you please help me out